# How to validate that a screen lock was not bypassed?

Tags: javascript, php

I plan to add a screen lock after certain amount of time so that if a user is idle he will need to enter his credentials again.

But is there a good way to validate that this screen lock was not bypassed? My solution was to save in the cache the last time the idle lock was triggered and the last time credentials were entered and compare if the time matches

But is there a better solution without using cache?

Comment: If you are asking for credentials, I’d take that to mean that the user’s session is over, and you are just providing a convenient way to re-login. Any attempt at “bypassing” shouldn’t work because the next HTTP request to hit your app would redirect to the login page.

Comment: Generally you just have a heartbeat script (or similar) and when it notices the dead session, it activates the dialog. But also, to support multiple tabs, if the script notices a valid session it closes any open re-login dialogs. If you use nonces tied to sessions, you might need to figure that out, too.

Comment: In my case it's not exactly that the user's session is over. I was planning to create an idle time but keep the user session live until later. So there are 2 points of time: the idle time trigger, and then the session ending time if the user doesn't respond, which is a bit later (but now there's the screen lock that requires the user to enter the credentials). Because I don't want to refresh the page after the screen lock (Because I need to update the CSRF and session cookie, I'm using Laravel - unless I can actually update them without refreshing the page?)

Comment: I guess, if the user’s session isn’t over, and they bypass the prompt somehow, who cares really? Eventually the session logic is going to terminate them, or it will renew and everyone is happing. If someone bypasses a convenience, that’s on them